# Can we run selenium tests without using Webdriver interface in your code?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to run Selenium test without using Webdriver interface in my code. the code is working as expected without any issues.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Java learning//Selenium//Drivers//chromedriver.exe");

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.get("https://ui.freecrm.com/");

WebElement loginbtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui fluid large blue submit button']"));

driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",loginbtn);
```

I am wondering how this worked fine without using Webdriver interface.I would like to know what is the difference between using webdriver and without using Webdriver ? I observed that FindElement method have return type as WebElement-Remotewebdriver. But when i used Webdriver interface,i observed that FindElement method have return type as WebElement-Webdriver. I would like to know if we do not use Webdriver, all the methods will be executed somewhere but not in local machine.

Comment: `ChromeDriver implements WebDriver`. Are you asking why you could use the more specific type?

Comment: I would like to know what is the difference between using webdriver and without using Webdriver ? is there any impact on the tests ?

Comment: Your code will run the same either way, it's just better practice to use the more generic type.

Answer (score 0):

ChromeDriver implements the WebDriver interface, so you are using it.

I would suggest a read of this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html