# Difference between running Selenium test with using Webdriver and without using webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, remotewebdriver

Without using **webdriver**, I observed that `driver.FindElement` method have return type as `WebElement-Remotewebdriver`.

With using Webdriver,I observed that `FindElement` method have return type as `WebElement-Webdriver`.

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https://ui.freecrm.com/");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui fluid large blue submit button']"));
```

If Chromedriver is implementing the Webdriver interface, why I am seeing the return type of `findElement` as `Webelement-RemoteWebdriver` rather than `Webelement-Webdriver`?

And I know that `RemoteWebdriver` class implements `Webdriver` interface. When the `remotewebdriver` will be used and why?

Comment: How do you run a Selenium test *without* using WebDriver?

Comment: This is a rehash of  [Can we run selenium tests without using Webdriver interface in your code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149640/can-we-run-selenium-tests-without-using-webdriver-interface-in-your-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SearchContext` is a root interface that is extended by `webdriver` and `webelement` interface.

So when we talk about webdriver interface, there are two classes that implements this interface

- EventFiringWebDriver.
- RemoteWebDriver.

There are 6 classes that extends RemoteWebDriver class like `ChromeDriver`, `FF`, `IE`, etc.

See what the **official documents** says :

You can use **WebDriver** **remotely** the same way you would use it **locally**. The primary difference is that a remote **WebDriver** needs to be **configured** so that it can run your tests on a **separate machine**. A remote WebDriver is composed of two pieces: **a client and a server**. The client is your **WebDriver** test and the server is simply a Java **servlet**, which can be hosted in any modern **JEE** app server.

For more you can refer :  [official Link](https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/remote.html)

Q.  If Chromedriver is implementing the Webdriver interface, why I am seeing the return type of findElement as Webelement-RemoteWebdriver rather than Webelement-Webdriver?

Ans :  **Chromedriver** is a public class which do not implement **Webdriver** interface.
and extends RemoteWebDriver protected class.

Comment: In the below link, i see that Chromedriver implements the webdriver.  I am little confused here. Can you please explain liitle bit more https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html